# SSIS Execute Process Task for C# Google Analytics api call error saying invalid application for OS

Tags: c#, ssis, google-analytics-api

I have an SSIS master package that contains several execute process tasks that run c# applications that pull data through Google Analytics reporting api.  Everything runs fine locally but when I deploy to the ssis server one of them fails with the following error:

"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2, but I wouldn't think it would matter since other, nearly identical tasks run fine and the fact they all run fine locally is driving me nuts.

All of the properties are the same between the tasks and the applications, the code is identical in the applications except the dimensions and metrics being pulled from Google Analytics and the database tables the data is being stored in.

I'm at a complete loss, any ideas on what else to check?

I've googled the error message with no results.

I've rewritten the failing application by copying and pasting the code of the working applications and making the tweaks to change the metrics and dimensions being requested as well as the table to import it into.

I've recreated the process task in ssis, copying a task that works and just changing the name and the location of the exe.

Comment: Can you share what components are you running in your task? 3rd party stuff or anything?

Comment: Is "the specified executable" clearly the C# application in a .exe file?

Comment: Jeric, no components.  Just referencing the Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4 library.

Comment: lit, yeah, definitely calling the exe of the c# application. I've got 9 other applications calling GA and all of them work locally and when deployed except the one calling the sessions, it works locally, but not when deployed.